# angular - controller excute more than 1 time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know it's asked before, but can't find solution that works for me.
I get each controller start 3 times!

It's problematic for me because I have sound in my app and it's display 3 times.

I'm new to angular. i don't know if it's meaningful but i have all controllers defined in one file `controllers.js`. I check and the file `app.js` called only once.

this is my app.js:

```
'use strict';

/* App Module */

var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'phonecatAnimations',
  'ui.router',
  'phonecatControllers',
  'phonecatFilters',
  'phonecatServices',
  'ui.utils',
  'angularCircularNavigation',
  'timer'      
]);

phonecatApp.config(['$stateProvider',
  function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {    
      var home = {
          name: 'home',
          url: '',
          views: {
              '': {
                  templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
                  controller: 'HomeCtrl'
              }
          }
      };  

      var learn = {
          name: 'learn',
          url: '/learn',
          views: {
              '': {
                  templateUrl: 'partials/learn.html',
                  controller: 'learnCtrl'
              }
          }
      };    

      var articles = {
          name: 'articles', 
          url: '/articles',
          views: {
              '': {
                  templateUrl: 'partials/articles.html',
                  controller: 'articlesCtrl'
              }
          }
      }; 

      $stateProvider.state(articles);
      $stateProvider.state(learn);
      $stateProvider.state(home);   
  } ]);
```

thanks!

Comment: Are you sure its controller problem? add log into controller to see it printed 3 times.

Comment: yes, each contoller excute 3 times

Answer (score 1):

From my experience the most common issue that leads to controller double calling is:

You have controller call from `$stateProvider` state, at the same time you call controller from HTML.

For example consider:

```
$stateProvider 
        .state('sidemenu.groups', {
            url: "/groups",
            views: {
                'mainContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/groups/groups.html',
                    controller: 'GroupsCtrl' // <-- 1st call
                }
            }
        })
```

and in HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="GroupsCtrl"></div> <!-- 2nd call -->
```

So remove `ng-controller`

---

Hope it will help you

Comment: thanks.. but it's not the problem. the only html file with the word 'contoller' is in index.html -  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

decided to use $routeProvider instead and the problem solved..